# Google Analytics 4 Data API Item Scope

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Dimension fields from user and custom events in Google Analytics via Python

```
user event-->name:"customUser:x_id"
custom event-->name:"customEvent:x_id"
```

I can get it as, but Item Scope is also defined, how can I get it?

```
"CustomItem:x_id" is not accepted.
```

solution via Python code

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: example: "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "date"
    },
    {
      "name": "itemId"
    }
    ,
    {
     "name": "customItem:Vendor"  ##get error
    }

Comment: Edit your question and include your full code. I would like to run it.   Can you be more clear as to what you think a "Item Scope" is?  There is no such thing as CustomItem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: example : google analytics custom dimension and scope

dimension name                scope User  Property/Parameter

Category Path Level Event Event category_path_level

Category Path Level Item Item         category_path_level

Comment: code
request = {
  "property": "properties/xxxxx",
  "date_ranges": [
    {
      "start_date": '2023-11-16',
      "end_date": '2023-11-16'
    }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "date"
    }
    
    #scope dimension to here  

  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "itemsViewed"
    }
  ]
      
        
}}

response = client.run_report(request)

Answer (score 0):

### Update in 2023/12/15

Now you can retrieve the data finally

the apiName is called "customItem:xxx"

So in your case : `customItem:x_id`

Have a try!

---

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9164320?hl=en#120523

GA4 update said **this customer item scope has been released to Data API**.

You can have a try on this and I will update here soon I can confirm this on my end

---

After some investigation and test.

Custom item scoped dimension is quite new and looks like not release the feature to `Data API` yet.

For GA4 there are always new feature like this and they will not release it to everywhere at once.

They will release the feature to report first. Then release to Data API or BigQuery at next stage.

Comment: so thanks @darreltw